# how to replace multiple words in a json file in R?

Tags: json, r, csv

I have a nested json file with sales information, and a part of the file is

```
"sales": {
      "sales_val": 22549
      "units_in_stock": 251
      "product_id": "0141602"
    }
```

I also have a csv file with product code and product name, like this

```
product_id product_name
0141602    toys for children 0-2 years
… etc …
0141230    wooden furniture
```

I cannot figure out how to replace every product code (in total there are more than 32,000 product codes) using `gsub` or an efficient method. In other words, I cannot find how to replicate these lines for every product code

```
file  <- readLines("sales.json")
replace  <- gsub(pattern = "001", replace = "toys", x = file)
writeLines(replace, con="sales2.json")
```

I did try to convert the json to `data.frame` and then use the `join()` function that comes with `plyr` package but that is not an efficient approach and I'm obtaining many NAs despite the list of codes is the full list of the store.

Comment: Is the `code` in csv file the `product_id` in json file?

Comment: Thanks. I've modified it to show a part of the original csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, kind of a guessing game here without a truly reproducible example. Just like @Psidom, I wonder if `code` in the csv was the same as `product_id` and json file.

However, here are some ideas / approaches that are probably useful to you:

Get the `jsonlite` package. the function `fromJSON` will easily parse your JSON and turn it into an R list. Then depending on how nested they are you can use either `unlist` (with recursive=FALSE option) or `do.call` with `rbind` depending on what you want to do.

Assuming that code and product_id are the same you could simply use `merge`. If you do so, give the two columns the same and it will work at once (you can use different column names for merging.. but it's easier if they got the same name.

Joining 32'000 on a single index does not sound like a big deal to me. So merge (which is rather slow) should do the job. In case it takes too long for you, please consider the `data.table package`. The syntax is different, but the package is astonishingly fast and well programmed. So If you encounter performance issues merging dataset, data.table might be a good option for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. "Code" was "product id" in the original csv files. The codes contained in the csv files are the same as in the json files.

Comment: In that case it is easy to do with merge . if that's too slow look into data.table. but I doubt you need to.